# How to implement URL filtering of classic asp pages

Tags: asp-classic, isapi

Greetings!

I have a website with classic asp pages in IIS 6.0. I'm trying to implement URL filtering of .asp requests to avoid Cross-Site Scripting attacks in URL. Please let me know the ways it can be implemented.

I have written as a common function and calling the function from each page.(Not a best practice).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into the option of installing an ISAPI filter on the server? Do you have access to install software?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `server.HTMLEncode()` on any `request.form` or `request.querystring` used on the asp pages.

In addition parametering any SQL variables may also help